# Comparative and superlative adverbs?

Tags: adverbs, comparatives, superlative-degree

I'm a native speaker of English, and I don't know how many times I've wanted to say "happilier" instead of "more happily", or "happiliest" instead of "most happily". Is there any record of such comparative/superlative adverbs (-lier, -liest) being used, even if it is in weird experimental literature?

Interesting problems arise with words already ending in "-ly", e.g.:

- `sillily`: in a silly manner
- `sillilier`: in a sillier manner
- `sillilily`: in a manner suggesting a silly manner (double-adverb)
- `sillililiest`: in a manner suggesting the silliest manner possible

(Typeset in fixed-width not because I think it's right, but because otherwise it's impossible to read "sillililiest".)

Comment: *Sillily* is a word: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sillily

Comment: Semantically, I am not sure what a double-adverb would mean, but I don't know why it should mean "in a manner *suggesting* [adverb]".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Oh, have some fun with it. What else would it mean?

Comment: Actually, the reason I was saying that I don't know what a double-adverb would mean, was because I was trying to speculate as to whether someone would have used it before (since I've never seen it, in any case).  *Sillilier* is not a word, but in the right situation, the intended meaning is clear ("more sillily"); so, I could picture someone using it humorously.  For the double-adverb ones, I can't come up with any possible meaning for it, so it is much more unlikely to have been used, even for humorous effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as your `silly` experiment, your problem arises in that `ly` is used to convert an adjective into an adverb, with the definition "in a [adjective] manner".

Thus, `sillily` is a word ("in a silly manner")

As far as "in a sillier manner", there are two rules for forming a superlative from an adverb. If the adverb was formed by adding `ly` to an adjective, you must use `most` or `more`.

"In a sillier manner" -> `more sillily`

"In the silliest manner" -> `most sillily`

If an adverb is the same as the adjective form, you can make a superlative using `er` or `est`

"In a faster manner" -> `faster` (ex. "He ran faster")

"In the fastest manner" -> `fastest` (ex. "He ran fastest")

As for `sillilily`, this is entirely nonsense. The reason is that our `ly` rule only applies to adjectives. You can not apply `ly` to an adverb and expect a "double adverb". An attempt to apply the rule directly would result in:

"In a sillily manner"

Notice that since `manner` is a noun, it should not have an adverb describing it. In your examples the word "suggesting" came out of nowhere. Nothing in the grammatical construction implied that there was suggestion.

In the case of `sillililiest` we encounter both of the above problems simultaneously. First, you attempted to make an adverb from an adverb by adding `ly`

`sillily` -> `sillilily`

Then you attempted to apply `est` or `er` to make a superlative

`sillilily` -> `sillililiest`

Both of these can not be done. The first because `ly` only applies to adjectives, not adverbs. The second because to make a superlative from an adverb which was formed by adding `ly`, you must use 'more' or 'most'. Again- you introduced the word "suggesting" which came out of nowhere.

Comment: Would someone mind explaining the down vote? I thought the explanation was quite clear. `ly` turns adjectives into adverbs but cannot be used on adverbs. Then a superlative is formed from an adverb in one of two ways depending on if it's an adjective+`ly` adverb or an adverb in its own right.

Comment: +1 for a good analysis. Bad form from the down-voter who didn't say why so the answer could be improved upon by the author.