# What is the analog equivalent of 'digitally'?

Tags: antonyms

In electronics, we can solve a problem digitally or *analoguely* ?

That doesn't sound right, but surely there must be a word I can use?

---

**Update**: some definitions:

*digitally:* Relating to or being a service that provides information expressed in discrete numerical form.

*analoguely:* Relating to or being a service that provides information expressed in continuous, non-discrete form. **(This is my made up definition of a word I made up)**.

*analogously:* Similar or alike in such a way as to permit the drawing of an analogy.

As you can see, the word *analogously* doesn't mean the opposite of *digitally*, it means something else.

Comment: I don't think that *analogously* is the antonym of *digitally*. The antonym of *digital* is the **adjective** *analogue*, not *analogous*.

Comment: @Andrew: It is used in this context though.

Comment: Your edit seems to have answered your question...

Comment: @ermanen English teachers correct many repeated mistakes.

Comment: @ermanen - I have never seen it used in this context, nor have I been able to find it defined like this in any dictionary. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @oerkelens English teachers might not accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: 'Insegreviously' is a better candidate than 'analoguely' at this point in time. At least some people have heard of it.

Comment: You can search analogously and digitally together. And you can search in Google Books. It is even used in electronics books.

Comment: ...Yes, you're right. 'Analogously' is also used with the more common meaning in the near vicinity of 'digitally', which is just asking for trouble. I haven't seen a dictionary stating that the usage has reached acceptable status.

Comment: As suggested in your question, why not *continuously*?

Comment: @Edwin, ermanen: I found a few dozen examples in Google Books, but I wouldn't accept the usage myself. So far as I'm concerned, ***analogously*** is either *in accordance with or by means of **analogy***, or *correspondingly, equivalently; comparably, similarly*, as per OED's only two definitions. I could only endorse ***by analogue means*** or something similar as the opposite of *digitally*.

Comment: @bib - Because, unless I was talking to an engineer, the reader may not understand the connection between analogue and continuous. Even an engineer would probably first read the word continuous as meaning something about not interrupting something.

Comment: "**Analogously**" might be in the process of semantic extension to cover this sense. So we may accept as a neologism because it is not in common use.

Comment: @ermanen: And why shouldn't we accept **"analogly"** as a less-confusing neologism?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you are talking about 'by analogy', my Oxford Dictionary says the word is 'analogically'.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Why not? Go ahead.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Analogly is also used in this sense but seems like a less commonly used neologism. Though this may need a deeper research.

Comment: Actually, @WS2's suggestion of *analogically* seems to be the most commonly used word for this purpose (that is, it received the most hits in the phrase *"digitally or analog(ically/ously/ly)"*.

Comment: @PeterShor That was my first thought until I discovered 'analogically' to mean 'by analogy'.

Comment: Well even "analog" is used as an adverb :) There is even confusion between neologisms but I still think "analogously" is better because of its formation. I will leave it to you.

Comment: @WS2: Well ... *"analog computers"* are called that because operate *"by analogy"*, so there's nothing etymologically wrong with using *"analogically"*.

Comment: @PeterShor  Yes. Point well made. Spelled 'analogue' in Britain. Your computing example corresponds with meaning B1 of the OED, which is summarised as follows: . 'adj. Typically contrasted with digital.
 1.
Categories »
 
 a. Of a computer or calculator: that operates by the manipulation of continuously variable physical quantities (as voltage, spatial position, or time) which are analogues of the quantities being computed. Cf. digital adj. 2b. Now chiefly hist.'
**So analogically it is!** Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet I happen to be looking for a solution to this myself for an article that I am writing.  I totally agree, such a word should exist, if it doesn't already.  IMHO, since digital implies something that is discrete, while analog(ue) implies something continuous, I would say, to do something via digital means it is done discretely (*not discreetly*), to do something via analog(ue) means it is done **continuously**.  This goes back to digital signals being discrete waveforms/functions, and analog(ue) singals being continuous waveforms/functions.

Answer (score 5):

Analoguely would probably be technically correct, except it's such an awkward form it's never come into usage.

One solution would be to rephrase the sentence to avoid it.

"In electronics, we can have a digital or an analogue solution for a problem."

Comment: How can a word be technically correct? From a consideration of morphology? So is _leisurelyly_ a 'technically correct' adverbial form?

Comment: @Edwin: It would be  *leisurelily*, which I'm not sure is a word (since *leisurely* is already an adverb as well as an adjective, there's no need to further adverbify it). We do [have](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107003/are-the-words-sillily-uglily-friendlily-livelily-etc-valid-english) *sillily, uglily, holily* etc. And people use *quantumly*, even if it isn't in the dictionaries.

Comment: ... Why? Why should _slyly_ be unique? I'm of course arguing that as there are no universal rules, the descriptor 'technically correct' is wrong.

Comment: @Edwin: it's not unique. There are also *dryly, shyly,* and  *wryly*.

Comment: I thought I'd let you do the digging. _Near-unique_. Just the five ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but nobody has come to any conclusion so I will post this.

I am Brazilian and speak Portuguese, and "analog" in Portuguese is "analógico". Now, why does it matter? it matters because we have many words that end like that, like the adjective "lógico", and most of their translations into english end in the same way as it's translation, "logical". Analog (or analogue) is an exception to that, as if it followed the pattern coming from Latin it would actually be spelled "analogical". From that we can see that the right spelling of "analoguely" would be "analogically", since it makes sense when compared to the respective form of similar words stemming from Latin, and would also look like the similar words in Portuguese when translated into english.

Please let me know if I'm wrong, and why.

Comment: This is a very interesting reply.  Looking up the etymology of the words, I can see that analog comes from Ancient Greek: análogos, “proportionate”, while logic comes from Ancient Greek too: logikós, “of or pertaining to speech or reason or reasoning, rational, reasonable”. Well, "rational" and "proportionate" are similar in meaning, so it makes sense that these words could be connected.

Answer (score 2):

In electronics, there are analogue solutions and there are digital solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In the electronics biz, it is common to refer to electronic components that are not intended for use in computers and other digital devices as **linear**.  In this sense the term has something of the same implication as "analog" does in "analog computer".

(Yes, someone might object that transistors are not "linear" in the strictest mathematical sense, but most uses of such components attempt to maintain a reasonably "linear" mode of operation, in that same mathematical sense.)