# What term describes a situation where conventional rules of grammar are unable to produce an idiomatically formed word for a particular context?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrase-requests, adverbs

I recently saw the question [Is the spelling beautifuly correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249118/73781) at ELL.

Before I even looked at it, I had thought of a joking response:

> ✘ No, it's **ugly** incorrect.

But I quickly stopped myself, realizing that wasn't right. I then very briefly thought of the following variations:

> ✘ No, it's **uglily** incorrect.
> ✘ No, it's **uglilly** incorrect.
> ✘ No, it's **ugily** incorrect.
> ✘ No, it's **ugilly** incorrect.

Of course, none of those is right either.

Although I'll note that each of those suggestions follows a generally correct approach to changing such an adjective into an adverb.

- *Happy* → *happily*.
- *Jolly* → *jollily*.

I'll add that [*ugly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ugly) ***is*** actually an adverb:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : in an ugly manner
> // was acting *ugly*

However, the sentence construction in which its adverbial form is grammatically used doesn't match the construction of the sentence I'm looking at here.

I'll also add—thanks to an answer provided in response to the original version of my question *before* this edit——that Merriam-Webster *does* actually show this:

> Other Words from *ugly*
> **Adjective**
> uglily \ ˈə-​glə-​lē \ *adverb*

I was surprised to have missed this, and to find that it exists in the first place. Still, I'd say that's so unusual that, even if it were expected by some audiences, most would mark as a mistake on the grounds of it being unidiomatic.

---

The sentence *could* be rephrased or the base word changed:

> ✔ It's **beautifully** correct.
>
> ✔ No, it's ***grotesquely*** incorrect.
> ✔ No, it's ***an*** ugly incorrect ***spelling***.

But that means either dispensing with *ugly* altogether, or altering the sentence to accommodate *ugly* in a way that *beautifully* does not require.

---

So, to restate:

> ✔ It's **beautifully** correct.
> ✘ It's (**ugly**) incorrect.

Is there a word that expresses the fact that *ugly* cannot be turned into an *acceptable* adverbial form in the same way that *beautiful* can be turned into *beautifully*?

In short, what word or linguistic descriptive term would be used to describe this so-called ***intransigent*** aspect of *ugly*?

If used in a sentence:

> In this context, the word *ugly* is _____.

The adjective (or phrase) should mean that the word cannot be reformed in a grammatically and idiomatically acceptable way.

I'm specifically focused on the word *ugly* and its inability to be turned into something acceptable, but, as with the title of this question, will be content with a word or phrase that describes this phenomenon in general.

Comment: What's amiss with [*uglily*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/107003/2085)? Meseems it fast-formed and fine-wrought.

Comment: [infelicitous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infelicitous)

Comment: @Mitch I like that, but I'm looking for something that refers to the original thing whereby if it *were* changed according to normal rules it would *become* infelicitous. In my question I suggest **intransigent**, because I think that's a general term for its nature in this context, but I was hoping for an actual linguistic term.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I believe that grammatically the word would be described as [defective](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/defective)

Comment: ['Infelicitous'](https://www.google.com/search?q=infelicitous+linguistics) is what linguists use in pragmatics for statement that are true of a situation but just not what you would say'. eg there are two cats sleeping in a room - it would be infelicitous to say "The cat is asleep". It's not a far cry to apply it analgously to a word form that follows the rules, but just sounds awful. 'Intransigent' applies to people.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, great. I didn't know that there was a domain-specific use for the word alongside its regular English use. You are correct, that is indeed just what I was looking for.

Comment: @JasonBassford *Infelicitous* and ***defective*** are not the same thing: the first is avoided out of an aversion to awkwardness or cacaphony, but the second is blocked as impossible because of a restriction in the syntax or morphology. You might sometimes find *sillily* despite its cumbersomeness, but just as you’ll never find a *cran* outside a *cranberry*, neither will you ever find *one cattle* on its own, or *beware* in the past tense, or *quoth* in the present tense, or *ought* in the gerund-participial form. It's like how you can die a good death, but a good death cannot be died by you.

Comment: Look into morphological derivation and productivity. And I bet there's a treasure trove of research for you to do starting here: [English adverbs ending in -lily](http://ontology.buffalo.edu/smith/varia/lily.htm). (See reference at end: Laurie Bauer, "Scalar productivity and -lily adverbs.")

Comment: @TinfoilHat See “Restricting Suffix Combinations in German and English: Closing Suffixes and the Monosuffix Constraint” by Mark Aronoff and Nanna Fuhrhop, *Natural Language & Linguistic Theory*, Vol. 20, No. 3 (Aug., 2002), pp. 451–490.

Answer (score 3):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.usage.english/qoIklspnMN8

> **What's the adverb that goes along with the adjective "ugly"?**
>
> Believe it or not, it's 'uglily'.  Ain't that ugly?
>
> There's a verb 'uglify', meaning 'make ugly', and from there we derive
>   the noun 'uglification', which Prince Charles recently hit the
>   headlines for using.  The Times described it as an 'excrescense'; I've
>   waited until now for a chance to mention that little irony.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ugly

Other Words from ugly
Adjective

uglily \ ˈə-​glə-​lē  \ adverb

Comment: Excellent. +1 for spotting that notation later on in the definition. I'd somehow missed it. So, it turns out that it can be turned into the type of adverb that I need. However, it still looks horribly wrong, and I'd say that it would be marked as incorrect by most audiences who read it in some kind of publication. So, I'm still wondering if there's a word that can be used to describe words like these that resist such manipulation.